# Users as Contacts in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am new to MS Dynamics CRM 2013, but I have a question regarding Users and Contacts sharing email addresses.  Is that possible, or more importantly would it create some conflict.  We integrate the CRM with a CMS system and need to have users in the CRM as Contacts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is technically possible for Users and Contacts to share Email Addresses.
It is, however, a best practice to to avoid having multiple records (of any entity) with the same email address since it will cause some conflicts in the application.

For example, when tracking emails, Dynamics CRM attempts to resolve the recipients to existing records in CRM so that the Email will appear in their Activity list.

Or when using Dynamics CRM Client for Outlook and tracking CRM activities (such as appointments) in Outlook, the application will go to the CRM database and query for entities that have an e-mail address associated to it. This could be a user, contact, account or lead. Once the application find an e-mail address that corresponds to the sender or recipients e-mail address, it will then associate the activity to that particular entity.